# How to reverse an std::string?

Tags: c++, string, binary, reverse

Im trying to figure out how to reverse the string `temp` when I have the string read in binary numbers

```
istream& operator >>(istream& dat1d, binary& b1)    
{              
    string temp; 

    dat1d >> temp;    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read in binary numbers"?  That the string will have something like "1100110"?  That you're reading a binary file off of disk?

Answer (score 112):

I'm not sure what you mean by a string that contains binary numbers.  But for reversing a string (or any STL-compatible container), you can use `std::reverse()`.  `std::reverse()` operates in place, so you may want to make a copy of the string first:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string foo("foo");
    std::string copy(foo);
    std::cout << foo << '\n' << copy << '\n';

    std::reverse(copy.begin(), copy.end());
    std::cout << foo << '\n' << copy << '\n';
}
```

Comment: It should be a void function since it does not return a value

Comment: `std::reverse` **is** a `void` function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse .

Comment: @MaxLybbert Yes, **however**, `main()` as it is implemented is not `void`  and should return a value. This is what @Wilhelm was trying to point out.

Comment: I can add the "return 0", but it so happens that C++ has a special case for `main`: "if control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`" ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function , 4th item on the special properties list).

Answer (score 64):

Try

```
string reversed(temp.rbegin(), temp.rend());
```

**EDIT**: Elaborating as requested.

`string::rbegin()` and `string::rend()`, which stand for "reverse begin" and "reverse end" respectively, return **reverse iterators** into the string. These are objects supporting the standard iterator interface (`operator*` to dereference to an element, i.e. a character of the string, and `operator++` to advance to the "next" element), such that `rbegin()` points to the last character of the string, `rend()` points to the first one, and advancing the iterator moves it to the *previous* character (this is what makes it a reverse iterator).

Finally, the constructor we are passing these iterators into is a string constructor of the form:

```
template <typename Iterator>
string(Iterator first, Iterator last);
```

which accepts a pair of iterators of any type denoting a range of characters, and initializes the string to that range of characters.

Comment: On your second line, did you mean to type "string reverse(.....)" instead of "string reversed(.....)" ? In other words, should the word "reversed" be "reverse" ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 it's just a variable name, can be anything

Comment: @HighCommander4 how did u get those rbegin, rend? i dont have those, only begin(), end()

Comment: @datdinhquoc They are new in C++11, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin