# C++: Creating a word "letter after letter" in string data type

Tags: c++, string

I'm learning C++ for my exam and one thing is bugging me.
I had a file with 25 words (let's call it "new.txt") and a file with 1000 words ("words.txt").
I had to check how many times a word from new.txt appears in words.txt. And after this I had to check how many times does a "mirror" of a word for new.txt appears in words.txt (mirror meaning the word from right to left => car = rac..)

My idea was to make three arrays: newword[25], words[1000], mirror[25] and then go one from there.

I know how to do this with "char" data type. But i wanted to try doing it with "string" type.

Here is the code:

```
string mirrors(string word) //function that writes the word from the back 
{
    int dl=word.length();
    string mir;

    for (int q=0;q<dl;q++)
    {
        mir[q]=word[dl-q-1]; //first letter of a new word is a last letter of the original word
    }

    return mir;
}




int main()
{

    ifstream in1 ("words.txt");
    ifstream in2 ("new.txt");

    string words[1000], newword[25], mirror[25]; //creating arrays


    for (int x=0;x<1000;x++) //filling the array with words from words.txt
    {
        in1>>words[x];
    }

    for (int y=0;y<25;y++) //filling the array with words from new.txt
    {
        in2>>newword[y];
    }

    in1.close();
    in2.close();


    for (int z=0;z<25;z++)
    {
        mirror[z]=mirrors(newword[z]);
    }

    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the problem...
When I'm changing the order of the letters, the string from "mirror" does not print using normal cout<

So my question is... Is there something with string data types that makes it impossible to print using one command after creating a word letter after letter, or is there something I have no clue about?

Because the word is there, it is created in this array. But cout<

I'm sorry if the question is not clear but it's my first time posting here...

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword word in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: Actually I was using a different name when programming. I just wanted to make it more clear here. But I will change because I didn't know it's reserved...

Comment: Ok. In `mirrors` you need to stop swapping when you reach the middle of the string.

Comment: In `mirrors`, you cant index into an empty string. call resize() first or... simply: `return string(word.rbegin(), word.rend());`

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Why is that? I'm taking the last letter from an word and putting it as a first letter of a totally new word in mirrors.

Comment: "My idea was to make three arrays: newword[25], words[1000], mirror[25] and then go one from there." this is a bad idea. Just have `std::set` with content from "new.txt" and read a word from "words.txt" one by one and count.

Comment: @Borgleader could you explain this one a bit more? It looks like you have the answer but I simply don't understand the technical side

Comment: @JakubKrysztofiak he means that doing `mir[whatever_number]` for empty string is wrong, that would not change size of string as you assumed, use `mir +=` instead, or change size of `mir` before that loop properly

Comment: Ok. I think that now everything is clear :D Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: Ignore my comment. I thought you were doing an in-place reversal.

Comment: Also see other posts on how to reverse a string like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951796/how-to-reverse-an-stdstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string mirrors(string word) {
    int dl = word.length();
    string mir; // here you declare your string, but is's an empty string.
    for (int q = 0; q < dl; q++) {
//      by calling mir[q] you are referencing to the [0, 1 ... dl-1] char of empty string (so it's size = 0) so it's undefined bhv/error.
//      mir[q]=word[dl-q-1]; //first letter of a new word is a last letter of the original word
        mir = mir + word[dl - q - 1]; // you rather wanted to do smth like this
    }
    return mir;
}
```

- using new as a variable name is not a very good idea as @Johny Mop pointed
- Jbc to możesz też po polsku zadać pytanko w komentarzu :).

Comment: you do not have to initialize `std::string` this way it has proper default ctor

Comment: So the problem is with the fact that I'm trying create an empty string, what simply is not possible. Dzięki za pomoc :D

Comment: It is possible string mir = "" is an example of creating empty string.
The problem is similar to the array out of bounds:
int t[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
cout << t[10]; // wrong index, t has only indexes 0..9
Strings like arrays has size, string a = "aaa" has size 3, and you can do operations like a[0], a[1], a[2], but a[3] is not allowed

Comment: You got it wrong, create and empty string is easy, you cannot access symbols through `operator[]` on empty string

Comment: You can check the size of string by calling method string_name.size(); You can reference only to indexes < string_name.size()  (and >= 0), and you can't reference to indexes  >= string_name.size() (and < 0).

Comment: Ok. Now now i understand the problem :D thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

First of all you try to access symbols in empty `std::string`, which leads to UB. In practice all of that is unnessesary:

```
std::string mirrors( const std::string &word) //function that writes the word from the back 
{
    return std::string( word.rbegin(), word.rend() );
}
```

is enough. As for your program, it would be much better to read content of file "new.txt" into memory, and `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` would be much better for lookup. Then create 2 instances `std::map<std::string,int>` (or `std::unordered_map` if you do not care of order) and read file "word.txt" one by one, count and update those maps accordingly:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> new_words; // this should be populated from file "new.txt"
std::map<std::string,int> counts, mcounts;
// reading loop of file "words.txt"
std::string word = ...;
counts[ word ] += new_words.count( word );
word = mirrors( word );
mcounts[ word ] += new_words.count( word );
```

then you would have all your counts.