# Unable to run reverse string program

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have recently started learning C++ and have written a few lines which accepts a string, displays the number of characters in it and also displays the reverse of the input string. This is what I have written.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

{
  char string[25],rev_string[25];
  int counter=0,length=0;

  std::cout << "\n Enter the string : ";
  std::cin >> string;

  while(counter==!'\0')
  {
    counter=counter+1;
    length=length+1;
  }
  counter=0;

  std::cout << "The string has "<<length<<" characters in it.";
  while(length>=0)
  {
    rev_string[counter]=string[length];
    counter=counter+1;
    length=length-1;
  }

  std::cout << "\n The reverse of the given string is : "<<rev_string;

  return(0);
}
```

There is no error when I debug, however when I run the program, I get some unexpected value and the string length shows zero. Can you please point out where have I made mistakes.

This is what I get when I run the program.

[image]

Comment: `==!'\0'` is not what you want.  Try `!='\0'`.   And perhaps something other than counter?

Comment: In c++ you should use `std::string` instead of `char[]`

Comment: Also see [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse). If you can't use `std::reverse` then I would expect to see a `std::swap` somewhere. And of course you have [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/198199/608639), [How to reverse an std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4951796/608639) and friends.

Comment: And without std::reverse, you will want to start with a pointer to the start and end character and then swap `while (end > start)` (don't swap over the entire string or you will end up reversing the string twice and ending up right back where you started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ( counter == !'\0' ) { … }
```

Well, `!'\0'` is `true`, which as an integer is `1`.  So you have `while (counter == 1)`, and `counter` is initialized to `0`, making the expression immediately `false`, so the loop never executes.

You probably meant to write `!= '\0'`.  But this is still a problem, since `counter` starts off with the value `0`, and `0 != 0` is still `false` and the loop doesn’t loop.

When you input `Hey` as your string, the characters `H`, `e`, `y`, and `\0` are placed in the `string` variable.   You want to find where that `\0` character is, which we see is at `string[3]`.  So why are you comparing `counter` with `'\0'`?  Maybe you want `string[counter]`?

---

When you get the number of characters in `Hey`, which is `3`, you begin your reverse loop copying the `\0` at index 3 to index `0` ... all 4 characters in the reverse order:  `\0`, `y`, `e`, `H`.  Unfortunately, the `\0` at the start will mark the end of the string, so the string will appear empty..

Comment: I somehow got the program to show how many characters are their in it by fixing     `while(counter==!'\0')`   by changing it to     `while(string[counter]!='\0')`  . But I still cant get the program to display the reverse string. It just shows blank now.

Comment: I added a line `length=length-1;` to prevent it from copying the `\0`. The program displays the reverse string this time, but it is followed by some random characters which are different every time I run the program.

Comment: Maybe you still need to copy the `\0` somewhere?

Comment: Added `rev_string[counter]='\0';` after the loop and now it works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

C++ is difficult to learn if you learn it as C. And also you get some ugly habits. Please learn and practice C++.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    std::cout << "number of characters: " << s.size() << std::endl;

    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::cout << "reverse string: " << s << std::endl;
}
```

This is how you write your problem in C++. Now compare with what you are trying to do and I think it speaks for itself.