# Alternative for a loop in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, loops, reverse

I want to reverse a string without the use of a loop. My code with the loop looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string reverseString(string str) {
    string changedString;
    int strLength = int(str.length() - 1);
    for(int i {strLength}; i >= 0; i--) {
        changedString.push_back(str.at(i));
    }
    return changedString;
}

int main() {

    string str;

    cout << "Enter a string to reverse it:\n" << flush;
    cin >> str;
    cout << reverseString(str) << flush;
}
```

Now I need to write a function without the loop. Only the methods of String should be used. Can you help me solving this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse an std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951796/how-to-reverse-an-stdstring)

Comment: btw as you pass the string by value, you could store the reversed in the parameter itself and remove the `changedString`, alternatively pass by reference to avoid the unnecessary copy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Comment: In order to repeat a process you are going to need a loop, whether you explicitly write one or you use a function that has a loop.  Even recursion can be considered a loop.

Answer (score 8):

It is very simple to write such a function

```
std::string reverse( const std::string &s )
{
    return { s.rbegin(), s.rend() };
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse( const std::string &s )
{
    return { s.rbegin(), s.rend() };
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "Hello World" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << reverse( s ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello World
dlroW olleH
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do that using recursion. Here are some links if you aren't aware what recursion is : [link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/) and [link2](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-recursion/).
Technically it won't be a loop.

```
string reverseString(string str, int index, string ans) {
    if (index == -1) return ans;
    ans += str[index];
    return reverseString(str, index - 1, ans);
}
```

Parameters for this function will be str as it was by default, index = size(str) - 1 and ans ans = "";
reverseString(str, size(str) - 1, "") for example.

If you want your function to take exactly one argument, then you can write wrapper function and the one I wrote will have different name - reverseStringWrapper for example and in reverseString there will be only one line - return reverseStringWrapper(str, size(str) - 1, "");

```
string reverseStringWrapper(string str, int index, string ans) {
    if (index == -1) return ans;
    ans += str[index];
    return reverseString(str, index - 1, ans);
}

string reverseString(string str) {
    return reverseStringWrapper(str, size(str) - 1, "");
}
```

Comment: The same could be achieved with one function and the appropriate default values in 2nd and 3rd argument. (Maybe, with start `index = 0` counting from end of `str`.)

Answer (score 1):

How was this?

- In c, You can use strrev() function to reverse the string(char*)
- In c++, you can either use std::reverse() or StringBuilder.reverse()
  method to reverse a string.

.
This way you can reverse the char array(char*).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Function to reverse a given character array using std::reverse
void reverse(char *str)
{
    std::reverse(str, str + strlen(str));
}

// main function
int main()
{
    /* using C string */
    char s[] = "Hello World";

    reverse(s);
    cout << "Reverse of the given string is : " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

This way you can reverse the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Function to reverse a given character array using std::reverse
void reverse(char* str)
{
    std::reverse(str, str + strlen(str));
}

// main function
int main()
{
    /* using C string */
    // char s[] = "Techie Delight";
    string s = "hello world";
    int n = s.length(); 

    // declaring character array 
    char char_array[n + 1]; 

    // copying the contents of the 
    // string to char array 
    strcpy(char_array, s.c_str()); 
    reverse(char_array);
    s = char_array;
    cout << "Reverse of the given string is : " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this might Helps:)

Comment: The usage of `std::reverse` was already mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59049714/7478597) (and even without the needless copying of `std::string` to `char[]`). Btw. [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s are not part of C++ standard. And, why do you mention [tag:c]? The question is tagged [tag:c++] (and only [tag:c++]).

Comment: @Scheff There is no answers was mentioned the usage of `std::reverse` . This is different answer from other answer.

Comment: Concerning, `std::reverse()` you are right - my fault. (I overlooked that it works even without `std::reverse()`.) However, the rest is still true.